# Specific Time range in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, time

I have a time series xlsx data which has columns like the following one. I would like to get the row data that are in between 8:00:00 AM to 10:00:00 AM for my analysis. Can any one help me out?

```
Add         Velocity       Time
0.128835374 10.34912454 8:44:23 AM
0.20423977  8.078739988 8:47:01 AM
0.110629502 13.4081172  9:19:46 AM
0.088979639 5.057336749 9:24:02 AM
0.128835374 10.60785265 10:21:29 AM
0.20423977  9.46599837  10:23:06 AM

[num, txt] = xlsread('Consective_result.xlsx');
T = num(:,3);
TimeVector = datevec(T)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hint: use `xlsread` to import the data in MATLAB, and then select the appropriate rows of data in MATLAB.

Comment: I did that part and edited.
BTW this is a part of my analysis.

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it right.  Use the third column of your `txt` cell array, and skip over the first row so you don't get the time header.  I'm going to assume that your times are entered in as text.  Once you do this, just use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and determine those times that are later than 8:00 AM and less than 10:00 AM.  `datenum` can conveniently take in a cell array of strings, and it will output a numeric vector where each time string in your cell array is converted into its corresponding numerical representation.

Once you find those rows, you can filter out the rows in each of `num` and `txt` using what we just talked about before you continue.  Therefore:

```
[num, txt] = xlsread('Consective_result.xlsx');
times = txt(2:end,3); %// Get the 3rd column, skip 1st row
time_nums = datenum(times); %// Get the numerical representation of the times

%// Figure out those rows that are between 8:00 AM and 10:00 AM
times_to_choose = time_nums >= datenum('08:00:00AM') & time_nums <= datenum('10:00:00AM');

%// Remove those rows then continue
num(1 + times_to_choose) = [];
txt(1 + times_to_choose) = [];
```

Take special care that I added a `1` to the indices because we omitted the `time` header in your spreadsheet.  Now, `num` and `txt` should only contain those times that are between 8:00 AM and 10:00 AM.